# Remove table row after clicking table row delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

Solution can use jQuery or be plain JavaScript.

I want to remove a table row after user has clicked the corresponding button contained in the table row cell so for example:

```
<script>
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
 //no clue what to put here?
}
</script>

<table>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use jQuery `click` instead of using `onclick` attribute, Try the following:

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7zWB5/1/)

Comment: It's not working, I should let you know I'm dynamically adding my table rows $('.mytable tr:last').before(..... could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @like-a-trainee yes, you should delegate the events, try the updated answer.

Answer (score 39):

you can do it like this:

```
<script>
    function SomeDeleteRowFunction(o) {
     //no clue what to put here?
     var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
         p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
    </script>

    <table>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Works perfect and [YouMightNotNeedJquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for such simple task.

Comment: @Siren I was pretty sure this could have been done like this! A part the thank you, do you kindly have some link where it is explained your `parentNode`(s) chain? I'd like to properly understand the "calculation" you have done. Thank you, I was not able to get rid of it. And yes, I love the fact [YouMightNotNeedJquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Saved my day. Simplest and most straight forward answer.

Answer (score 12):

**Using pure Javascript:**

Don't need to pass `this` to the `SomeDeleteRowFunction()`:

```
<td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction"></td>
```

The onclick function:

```
function SomeDeleteRowFunction(event) {
      // event.target will be the input element.
      var td = event.target.parentNode; 
      var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
      tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Following solution is working fine.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this);">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this);">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this);">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function SomeDeleteRowFunction(btndel) {
    if (typeof(btndel) == "object") {
        $(btndel).closest("tr").remove();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have done bins on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa9

Answer (score 0):

As @gaurang171 mentioned, we can use .closest() which will return the first ancestor, or the closest  to our delete button, and use .remove() to remove it.

This is how we can implement it using jQuery click event instead of using JavaScript onclick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });
```

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th >Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th width="1%"></th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-001</td>
  <td >Ben</td>
  <td >25</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-002</td>
  <td >Anderson</td>
  <td >47</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-003</td>
  <td >Rocky</td>
  <td >32</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-004</td>
  <td >Lee</td>
  <td >15</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>
```