# Using JQuery to highlight table row only when clicking on 5th row-element or outfocussing of textbox in 3th row-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where rows can be highlighted once a row is clicked or a textbox is left.

My table is called "editTable" and the body of the table looks like this (rows are dynamically generated in a foreach loop so there can be more than one):

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
           blabla
        </td>
        <td>
            blabla
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="submit" id="item_Unitprice" />
       </td>
       <td id="total"></td>
       <td id="highlighter">
           <img src="~/Content/images/highlight.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the table highlighting works as follows:

```
// Highlighting table
$('#editTable').on('click focusout', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

This works, but now I want the table highlighting only to respond to a click on the 5th td-element in the rows (i.e. the highlight image) or when leaving the textbox in the 3th td-element for each row.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: What does 'leaving' mean, in context? `blur`, `mouseout`..?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: What Wolff said, or simply by using classes.

Comment: @Thomas leaving meanings focusout (unselecting the textbox by for example clicking tab).

Comment: @A.Wolff I heard about the nth-child selector and classes (Boaz). And I know I should probably use them, but since I am not that experienced with JavaScript or JQuery I do not know how to implement them. For example: $('#editTable td:nth-child(4)') ...et cetera, does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a solution by doing the following things:

(1) for highlighting on focusout I still use the old function:

```
// Highlighting table on focusout
$('#editTable').on('focusout', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

(2) for highlighting on a click I add a onclick event to the image like this:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/highlight.gif" onclick="highlight(this)" />
```

and add the following code to my JavaScript file (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553768/remove-table-row-after-clicking-table-row-delete-button) question for deleting a row after a click):

```
function highlight(o) {
    var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
    $(p).toggleClass('highlight');
}
```

This makes it work. Of course it would be prettier to combine the two into one but for now I am happy with the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `$('#editTable')` to `$('#editTable').eq(4)`

Comment: This does not seem to work. Probably since the .eq() selects the whole row and not a single td element. (?) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: My bad, it should be `$('#editTable tr').each(function(){$(this).find('td:nth-child(5)').on ... });