# Delete a table row by selecting one of that table row's cell

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('table').append("<tr><td id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>")
  });
  $('th').on('click', '#no', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th> Element</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='no'>X</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>
More
</button>
```

I want a row to be deleted when I click the X on that row. What code should I add to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove table row after clicking table row delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553768/remove-table-row-after-clicking-table-row-delete-button)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/wfLu3Lzu/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('table').append("<tr><td id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>")
    });
    $('table').on('click', 'tr #no', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th> Element</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id='no'>
        X
    </td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>
More
</button>
```

Event delegation should start from `table` till `tr #no`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('th').on('click', '#no', function(){
```

You should be using event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#no', function(){
```

Here is the working demo for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('table').append("<tr><td id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>")
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#no', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th> Element</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='no'>
      X
    </td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>
More
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep appending elements with the same ID, that are dynamically inserted after the event handler is bound.

You can easily create the element, with the event handler, at the time it's inserted, and use a class for styling rather than duplicate ID's

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#no').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    var tr  = $('<tr />'),
        td1 = $('<td />', {
          'class' : 'no',
          text    : 'X',
          on : {
            click : function() {
              tr.remove();
            }
          }
        }),
        td2 = $('<td />', {
          text : 'Example'
        });
  
    $('table').append(tr.append(td1, td2))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th> Element</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='no'>
      X
    </td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>
More
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      $('table').append("<tr><td onclick='removeRow(this)' id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>");
    });
});
function removeRow($this){
        $($this).parent().remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th> Element</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick='removeRow(this);'  id='no'>
        X
    </td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>
More
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow event delegation for dynamically created html elements.
check the bold code I have changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('table').append("<tr><td id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>")
    });
    **$(document)**.on('click', ''th' #no', function(){
        **$(this).parent('th:first').remove();**
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You `X` button is in `td` tag and you are trying to bind event on `th` tag.

can you please try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('table').append("<tr><td id='no'>X</td><td>Example</td></tr>")
    });
    $('table').on('click', '#no', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('tr').on('click', '#no', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will locate the td cliacked and remove the tr it was belong.

```
 $("td").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });
```

Hope it solved your porblem.