# dynamically delete row in javscript

Tags: javascript, crud, delete-row

I am new to javascript, need some help.

I am working on the `Add/Remove` feature to add and delete data from the table up on input. **Add** operation is working fine but I am not able to `delete` the row in the table.
I have gone through some of the doc and links but I am not getting.

Can someone help me with it?

**Code Snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 85px;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="age">Enter Age</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subject">Enter Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stusubject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="showName()" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
  </form>
  <table class="table container mt-5" id="studList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
        <th scope="col">Subject</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  var student = [{
      nname: "abc",
      age: 18,
      subject: "eng"
    },
    {
      nname: "red",
      age: 20,
      subject: "math"
    }
  ]

  function showName() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var stusubject = document.getElementById("stusubject").value;

    console.log("firstName :", firstName);
    console.log("Age :", age);
    console.log("subject :", stusubject);

    // push the data in array
    var newstud = {
      nname: firstName,
      age: age,
      subject: stusubject,
    }
    student.push(newstud);
    //console.log(newstud);
    console.log(student);

    var table = ' <tr>' +
      '<td>' + firstName + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + age + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + stusubject + '</td>' +
      '<td> <input type="button" onclick="delName(r)"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"></td></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    $(table).appendTo('#studList tbody');
    console.log("table :", table);
  }

  //delete the row onclcik
  function delName(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("studList").deleteRow(i);
  }
  var table = ' <tr>' +
    '<td>' + firstName + '</td>' -
    +'<td>' + age + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + stusubject + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
  $(table).deleteRow('#studList tbody');
  console.log("table :", table);
</script>
```

Comment: You cant delete a row in jquery like this-  $(table).deleteRow('#studList tbody'); insted use the javascripts default command  -  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0); .
Just specify the row number

Comment: You haven't took a look at the console, `r` is not defined, and the inline listener throws an error when clicking on Delete button. Replace `r` with `this` in the `onclick` attribute. The most recommended way is to avoid inline listeners, and listen clicks on `tbody`, that way you need only a single listener. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove table row after clicking table row delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553768/remove-table-row-after-clicking-table-row-delete-button)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your below code:

Older:

```
<td> <input type="button" onclick="delName(r)"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"></td></td>
```

New: Add one rowId variable into your code which intital value is 0 and after that value is increment when new row added.

```
<td> <input type="button" onclick="delName(deletebtn'+rowId+')" id="deletebtn'+rowId+'" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"></td></td>
```

Please let me know if anything else

Comment: I also want that the element should be removed from the array when the user clicks on that row.

Comment: For that you need to set the unique identifiers into the student array and when remove that row then need to loop the student array and find index based on unique identification and after remove from that array.

Comment: Have you checked this one?

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your snippet and  changed the **delete** function:

- Remove `r` on `delName()` function, since it's **undefined**. But instead use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which references to the object onto which the event was dispatched.

Try to run the **code snippet** blow:

```
function delName() {
    var td = event.target.parentNode; 
    var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 85px;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="age">Enter Age</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subject">Enter Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stusubject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="showName()" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
  </form>
  <table class="table container mt-5" id="studList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
        <th scope="col">Subject</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  var student = [{
      nname: "abc",
      age: 18,
      subject: "eng"
    },
    {
      nname: "red",
      age: 20,
      subject: "math"
    }
  ]

  function showName() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var stusubject = document.getElementById("stusubject").value;

    console.log("firstName :", firstName);
    console.log("Age :", age);
    console.log("subject :", stusubject);

    // push the data in array
    var newstud = {
      nname: firstName,
      age: age,
      subject: stusubject,
    }
    student.push(newstud);
    //console.log(newstud);
    console.log(student);

    var table = ' <tr>' +
      '<td>' + firstName + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + age + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + stusubject + '</td>' +
      '<td> <input type="button" onclick="delName()"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"></td></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    $(table).appendTo('#studList tbody');
    console.log("table :", table);
  }

  //delete the row onclick
  function delName() {
    var td = event.target.parentNode; 
     var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
     tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  }
  var table = ' <tr>' +
    '<td>' + firstName + '</td>' -
    +'<td>' + age + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + stusubject + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
  $(table).deleteRow('#studList tbody');
  console.log("table :", table);
</script>
```

Reference: [table-row-delete-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553768/remove-table-row-after-clicking-table-row-delete-button)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the table property and make a div as a table in CSS flex and make their class same per row and IDs are different as follows

```
<div id='rowUserDataMain' class='row'><div class='name'></div><div class='age'></div><div class='email'></div></div>

$('#rowUserDataMain').children().remove();
```

//That's It!